# Typescript iterate over a Record type and return updated Record

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript2.0

I am new to **Typescript** and I need to iterate over a `Record` type make some updates to the values and return the `Record`.

This is how the types are defined:

```
type Parent = Readonly<Record<string, Children>>;
type Children = ReadonlyArray<string>;
```

Here is some sample data I would like to iterate over:

```
const data = {
    parent1: ["child1", "child2"],
    parent2: ["child1","child2"]
};
```

Method to update values in record:

```
const updateChildren = (child: Children) : Children => {
    return child.map( value => value + 'updated');
}
```

I am struggling to write the syntax for it, tried to look for examples but couldn't find anything helpful.

I am able to iterate over the record using `Object.entries`

```
Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(key, value));
```

I also tried to use `Object.keys`

```
Object.keys(data)
            .map(key => updateChildren(data[key]))
```

I guess I am close but not sure how to return the map as here its returning `Array [Array]`

Is there some nice way to iterate do the update and it would return the updated data in same type used.

Thanks for reading.

Here is the javascript snippet of what I am trying to do and get the `updatedMap` in example below.

```js
const data = {
    parent1: ["child1", "child2"],
    parent2: ["child1","child2"]
};

function updateChildren(children) {
  return children.map(child => child+'updated');
}

const updatedMap = new Map();

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  updatedMap.set(key, updateChildren(value));
}

updatedMap.forEach((value, key) => console.log(key + ":" + value));


console.log(Object.keys(data).map(key => updateChildren(data[key])));
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like this...

```
type Children = ReadonlyArray<string>;

const data: Parent = {
  parent1: ["child1", "child2"],
  parent2: ["child1", "child2"],
};


type MutableObject<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P] };

const updateChildren = (child: Children): Children => {
  return child.map(value => value + 'updated');
}

let newObj: Parent = Object.entries(data).reduce<MutableObject<Parent>>((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur[0]] = updateChildren(cur[1]);
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: I am trying to write something like this but for the `Parent` type instead of map in this snippet
`Object.keys(data).reduce((map, currentItem) => {
const updated = updateChildren(data[currentItem]);
return map.set(currentItem, updated)
}, new Map());` so if I can pass `{}` instead trying to come up with syntax for that.

Comment: Here is using reduce with {} rather than Map

https://repl.it/@risingBirdSong/GleefulDeepskyblueDatabase#index.ts

Comment: Not implemented but here's how you could type the Map

let mapTest = new Map<string, MutableObject<Children>>();

Comment: I have accepted the answer, you can update it to reflect the change in repl